# Как сменить заголовок в title c помощью php?

Tags: php

Создал index.php и style.php. Подключил файл style.php к index.php. Все импортируемые переменные работают кроме одной, точнее в одном месте, между тегами title.

Раньше главное всё работало как создал, а сейчас нет, с чем это связано? До этого я ещё устанавливал переменную для заголовка, но потом удалил, а как стал делать новую переменную, она не отображалась.

index.php

```
<?

    include("style.php"); //подлкючаем файл style.php

    $text="Программирование php"; $title="$index_tit";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title><? print $title; ?></title>

        <!--css подключается как в html-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    </head>

    <body>

        <?php

            echo "<$h1 id='cent'>$logo</$h1> <$p>$text</$p> <$p>$menu</$p>";    //class, id подключаются в теге переменной как в html

                                                                                //в class, id используются апострифы ('')

            print(date('d F, Y'));  //вывод даты на экран

        ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

style.php

```
<?php

    //переменные для заголовков

    $index_tit="site";

    //переменые для тегов

    $h1="h1"; $h2="h2"; $h3="h3"; $p="p"; $br="br"; $b="b"; $u="u"; $i="i";

    $menu="<a href='tip_dannih.php'>типы данных</a>";       //ссылки главного меню

    $tip_dannih="<a href='tip_dannih1.php'>строковые значения 1</a> <a href='tip_dannih2.php'>массив</a>";

    //название сайта

    $logo="PHP.RU";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title><? print $title; ?></title>

    </head>

</html>
```

Comment: Код в студию, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Answer (score 2):

Тайтл на самом деле отображаеться, достаточно будет заглянуть в исходный текст что отдает браузер и все станет на свои места.

Первым в браузер отдаеться html из style.php, там переменной title нет, именно этот пустой тайтл и берет браузер, после чего уже отдает html из index.php где выводит нужный тебе тайтл, но браузер его уже игнорирует, т.к. он уже определен.

И определять так переменные

```
 $title="$index_tit";
```

это совсем не тру

Answer (score 2):

Включите в настройках php `short_open_tag`, либо используйте вариант из первого ответа.